# Lightspark doesn't works in firefox 29.0 and Chromium 34.0.1847.116 (ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: firefox, flash, chromium

I need your help,

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I've installed Lightspark (lightspark 0.7.2-3ubuntu1) as an alternative to Adobe Flash Player. But Lightspark doesn't works both with Firefox 29.0 and Chromium 34.0.1847.116.

What and how do I do to make Lighspark run with both browsers?

I'm waiting your answer.

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: Lightspark probably won't work in Chromium 34, but it should work in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Lightspark currently does not support Chromium's only plugin API - PPAPI.

More information here: [FlashPlayer open source alternative](https://askubuntu.com/questions/576067/flashplayer-open-source-alternative)