# Alternative to memory hungry libpepflashplayer.so?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, chromium

When running`htop`, I almost always find several `libpepflashplayer.so` processes cosuming the majority of memory on my ubnutu 18.04. Presumably it's tied to a running chromium instance.

Is this normal? If not, what are some alternatives I could use to decrease memory consumption?

Comment: There is no alternative to the flash player because it's not a free software. Are you sure you need it?

Comment: @int_ua, sadly I do :( chromium relies on it.

Comment: Do you use any sites or services that require it? The `chromium-browser` only suggests `adobe-flashplayer`, I've removed it years ago and chrome looks ok.

Comment: @int_ua hm actually I'm not sure. Bit offtopic I guess, but do you know of a way to get more granular stats from `htop`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FlashPlayer open source alternative](https://askubuntu.com/questions/576067/flashplayer-open-source-alternative)